# How do you generate a random uint64 in Go?

Tags: random, go

Go's `math/random` library is missing a function to generate 64-bit numbers. This has been [an open issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4254) for about four years. In the meantime, what does a workaround look like?

Comment: That issue suggested using two random uint32's, any reason that doesn't work for you?

Comment: you can shift-OR two int32 numbers, or something similar. You can also use the crypto/rand package and copy a byte buffer to a uint64.

Comment: This should be fixed before the 1.8 release cycle is over at the end of October: https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/27253/1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit:** Go 1.8 added a [`rand.Uint64()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#Uint64) function and a [`Rand.Uint64()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#Rand.Uint64) method, so you can directly use those.

The rest of the answer pre-dates Go 1.8.

---

The easiest would be to call [`rand.Uint32()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Uint32) twice:

```
func Uint64() uint64 {
    return uint64(rand.Uint32())<<32 + uint64(rand.Uint32())
}
```

Another option is to call [`rand.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Read) ([was added in Go 1.7](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#minor_library_changes)) to read 8 bytes, then use the [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package to obtain a `uint64` value from it:

```
func Uint64() uint64 {
    buf := make([]byte, 8)
    rand.Read(buf) // Always succeeds, no need to check error
    return binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(buf)
}
```

Note: as the doc of `rand.Read()` states, it always reads as many bytes as the length of the passed slice, and it always returns `nil` error, so no need to check error in this case.

Note #2: you could also use `binary.BigEndian` instead of `binary.LittleEndian`, as we're generating a random number using all its bytes, order of bytes is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

You can call `rand.Uint64()` directly:

`r := rand.Uint64()`

> Uint64 returns a pseudo-random 64-bit value as a uint64 from the default Source.

https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Uint64

This is available in versions `1.8` and up: [changelog](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#math_rand)

Comment: Note that this would not be cryptographically secure and therefore not suitable for many applications.

Answer (score 3):

You can also read 8 random bytes, and convert to a uint64

```
b := make([]byte, 8)
_, err := rand.Read(b)
return binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(b), err
```

Answer (score 0):

while using `crypto/rand` is more secure than `math/rand` and some linter complaining about it with **G404: Use of weak random number generator (math/rand instead of crypto/rand)**

I recommend something like the  following function

```
func Int64() int64 {
nBig, err := cryptoRand.Int(cryptoRand.Reader, big.NewInt(math.MaxInt64))
if err != nil {
    return 0
}
return nBig.Int64()
```

}