# Random 64-bit integer from crypto/rand

Tags: go, random

I want to generate 64-bit random integer using the secure `crypto/rand` package. I found this online:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
)

// GenerateRandomBytes returns securely generated random bytes.
// It will return an error if the system's secure random
// number generator fails to function correctly, in which
// case the caller should not continue.
func GenerateRandomBytes(n int) ([]byte, error) {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    _, err := rand.Read(b)
    // Note that err == nil only if we read len(b) bytes.
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return b, nil
}
```

But it seems to generate random bytes instead. I want a random 64-bit int. Namely, I want something like `var i uint64 = rand()`. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You can't figure out how to convert 8 random bytes into a random 64-bit integer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you generate a random uint64 in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756133/how-do-you-generate-a-random-uint64-in-go/39756320#39756320)

Comment: Not a duplicate, @icza. He wants to use cryptographic randomness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a random number with [`crypto.Rand`](https://godoc.org/crypto/rand#Read), and then convert those bytes to an int64 using the [`binary`](https://godoc.org/encoding/binary) package:

```
func randint64() (int64, error) {
    var b [8]byte
    if _, err := rand.Read(b[:]); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return int64(binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(b[:])), nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/2Q8tvttqbJ (result is cached)

If you look at the [source code for `LittleEndian.Uint64`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/binary.go#L75), you can see it's simply performing a few bit operations on the data; something that you could implemented for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know for the binary encoding package.

Answer (score 1):

You also use `rand.Int` in `crypto/rand` package

```
func randint64() (int64, error) {
    val, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(int64(math.MaxInt64)))
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return val.Int64(), nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/fqoQxpmjOSu